# Internet explorer 9 making lines and boxes that should not be there

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

On my home page in ie for some reason it makes a line about 3px high right about the content and right below the bread crumb bar. [example](http://stonerhideout.com).

Second problem, is that it also makes a box on this page
[example](http://www.stonerhideout.com/index.php?/forum/4-introduce-yourself/)

On the second example it messes with the user photo moves it into a box that should not be there. Along with the follow forum button. Which should be right below in the box as well. To see how it should look check those pages in any browser but ie. I really could use a fix for this. If its a css thing i have a ie specific css file i can put code in i just cant figure out what i need to put in there.
Also can someone check it out in ie 8 because i don't have it anymore and if there is a different fix maby you could help with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have something going on that's changing your HTML or your DOM based on the browser. Likely you either have some client or server side code that manipulating things in a browser-variant way.

For example, in IE you have two DIVs with ID "boardindex", but I only see one in Chrome. Use F12 and/or Firebug to further investigate the differences. Isolate the code that's causing the differences using a binary search method if necessary.

Comment: would posting the php of the pages help because i have tried firebug

Comment: Others with experience in PHP may be able to assist if you post some code.